# Serialize poco containing object property into Json

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, json.net, poco

I have a class that I need to serialize to pass to another system.

The class contains a property that is defined as an object, because the type of class the object will contain can vary at runtime.

My classes looks something like this simplified mock up;

```
public class MyTestXML
{
    public string String1 { get; set; }
    public string String2 { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("First", typeof(MyFirstObject),
                              Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Second", typeof(MySecondObject),
                              Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public object MyObject { get; set; }
}
public class MyFirstObject
{
    public string theFirstObjectString { get; set; }
}
public class MySecondObject
{
    public string theSecondObjectString { get; set; }
}
```

This class serializes perfectly to xml by using the XmlElementAttribute and XmlSerializer, but when I try and serialize it to Json (using Newtonsoft Json.Net), the object is of an undefined type, and it cannot be deserialized.

Is there a way to specify the XmlElementAttribute in Json attributes to achieve the same result when serialized?

I would like to offer the use of Json for the serialised object, as it is half the size of the xml, but cannot unless I can solve the serialization of the object property issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is `StringObject` of type `object`? And not of it's actual type?

Comment: @Yuval - The object property can be one of several different types...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create your own custom serialization behaviour. Have a look at this answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22722467/2039359 on how to implement your own [JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) for Json.Net

In your case you could do something like this to create your json

```
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            MyTestXML myTestXml = (MyTestXML) value;
            JObject jObject = JObject.FromObject(value);

            JProperty prop = jObject.Children<JProperty>().First(p=>p.Name.Contains("MyObject"));
            if (myTestXml.MyObject.GetType() == typeof (MyFirstObject))
            {
                prop.AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("First", JToken.FromObject(myTestXml.MyObject)));
                prop.Remove();
                jObject.WriteTo(writer);
            }
            else if (myTestXml.MyObject.GetType() == typeof (MySecondObject))
            {
                prop.AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("Second", JToken.FromObject(myTestXml.MyObject)));
                prop.Remove();
                jObject.WriteTo(writer);                    
            }
        }
```

And something like this when you are deserializing

```
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);

            MyTestXML myTestXml = new MyTestXML();

            serializer.Populate(jo.CreateReader(), myTestXml);

            object myObject = null;
            if (jo["First"] != null)
            {
                myObject = new MyFirstObject { TheFirstObjectString = jo["First"].SelectToken(@"TheFirstObjectString").Value<string>() };
            }

            if (jo["Second"] != null)
            {
                myObject = new MySecondObject { TheSecondObjectString = jo["Second"].SelectToken(@"TheSecondObjectString").Value<string>() };
            }

            myTestXml.MyObject = myObject;
            return myTestXml;
        }
```

To use it you would supply your `JsonConverter` when serializing/deserializing like so:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new MyTextXmlJsonConverter());
        var a = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myTestXml, settings);
```

Hope that's what you're looking for

Comment: I have accepted this solution as the answer, but it does seem over-engineered for something the xml serializer handles with attributes. I haven't tested yet, but will update answer when I can devote some time to it.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to create a custom contract resolver which would allow you to detect which xml attribute is applied.  You can then apply a custom JsonConverter on the property if you needed a specific output.

```
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly JsonMediaTypeFormatter formatter;

    public CustomContractResolver(JsonMediaTypeFormatter formatter)
    {
        this.formatter = formatter;
    }

    public JsonMediaTypeFormatter Formatter
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return this.formatter; }
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        this.ConfigureProperty(member, property);
        return property;
    }

    private void ConfigureProperty(MemberInfo member, JsonProperty property)
    {
        if (Attribute.IsDefined(member, typeof(XmlElementAttribute), true))
        {
            var attribute = member.CustomAttributes.Where(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(XmlElementAttribute)).First();
            // do something with your attribute here like apply a converter
            property.Converter = new XmlAttributeJsonConverter();
        }            
    }
}
```