# Update value in JObject, in JsonConverter ReadJson

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonconverter

I am trying to update/change a value in a class when I Deserializing a json.

I need to do this in a JsonConverter, but I am getting this error:
**Token PropertyName in state Property would result in an invalid JSON object. Path '[0]'.**

This is the my Class

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
public class MyMetaData
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("number")]         
    public string number { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stock")]
    public int stock { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the JsonConverter **MyConverter**

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var artId = (string)jObj["id"];
        int myNewStockValue = StockRepository.Get(artId);

        return new MyMetadata() {
          id = artId,
          number = jObj["number"],
          stock = myNewStockValue
        }
    }
```

Comment: id = artikelId,  should  be id = artId ??

Comment: Yes, sorry. I change it...

Comment: maybe this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718759/serialize-dynamic-property-name-for-an-object-using-json-net

Comment: What is the JSON you are deserializing?

Comment: Also, does your converter implement `WriteJson`?  If so, what does that code look like?

Comment: `Token PropertyName in state Property would result in an invalid JSON object. Path '[0]'` can only be thrown from `WriteJson()` not `ReadJson()`.  For us to help you with this exception we need to see that method.